# PreparedStatementCallback in sql with java

Tags: java, sql, list, dictionary

```
List<Integer> roles = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select role_id from user_roles where user_id = ?" , new Object[]{id});

    String roleIds= "";

    for (int i= 0; i < roles.size(); i++)
    {

           }            if (roles.get(i) != null) {
            if(i!=0){
                roleIds += "," + m.get(i) ;
            }else{
                roleIds += m.toString() ;
            }
        }
    }

    String queryString= "select u.id,u.user_id,count(distinct pf.id),IfNULL(upm.grievance_autoassign_enable,true) "+
            " from users u "+  
            " inner join user_roles ur on ur.user_id=u.id " +
            " left outer join user_preference_management upm on u.id = upm.id "+
            " inner  join management_hierarchy mh on mh.child_id = u.id or mh.role_id =ur.role_id "+  
            " left outer join ( jbpm4_task  jt "+ 
            " inner join process_flow pf on pf.pid = jt.execution_id_ and pf.grievance_mgmt_id is not null)  on jt.assignee_ = u.user_id "+
            " where mh.parent_id = ? "+ (roleIds != null ? " or mh.role_id in (" + roleIds + ")" : "") +
            " group by u.id,u.user_id  order by count(pf.id) ";

    return executeDBSummaryWithAutoAssign(queryString,new Object[] {id});
    }
```

My error log:

> PreparedStatementCallback; 
>   bad SQL grammar [select u.id,u.user_id,count(distinct pf.id),IfNULL(upm.grievance_autoassign_enable,true)  from users u 
>   inner join user_roles ur on ur.user_id=u.id  left outer join
>   user_preference_management upm on u.id = upm.id  inner  join
>   management_hierarchy mh on mh.child_id = u.id or mh.role_id
>   =ur.role_id  left outer join ( jbpm4_task  jt  inner join process_flow pf on pf.pid = jt.execution_id_ and pf.grievance_mgmt_id is not null) 
>   on jt.assignee_ = u.user_id  where mh.parent_id = ?  or mh.role_id in
>   ([{role_id=2}, {role_id=4}, {role_id=1}, {role_id=8}, {role_id=38},
>   {role_id=22}, {role_id=69}],[{role_id=2}, {role_id=4}, {role_id=1},
>   {role_id=8}, {role_id=38}, {role_id=22}, {role_id=69}],[{role_id=2},
>   {role_id=4}, {role_id=1}, {role_id=8}, {role_id=38}, {role_id=22},
>   {role_id=69}],[{role_id=2}, {role_id=4}, {role_id=1}, {role_id=8},
>   {role_id=38}, {role_id=22}, {role_id=69}],[{role_id=2}, {role_id=4},
>   {role_id=1}, {role_id=8}, {role_id=38}, {role_id=22},
>   {role_id=69}],[{role_id=2}, {role_id=4}, {role_id=1}, {role_id=8},
>   {role_id=38}, {role_id=22}, {role_id=69}],[{role_id=2}, {role_id=4},
>   {role_id=1}, {role_id=8}, {role_id=38}, {role_id=22}, {role_id=69}])
>   group by u.id,u.user_id  order by count(pf.id) ]; 
>       nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[{role_id=2},
>   {role_id=4}, {role_id=1}, {role_id=8}, {role_id=38}, {role_id=22},' at
>   line 1

Comment: You might need to provide some more details, but the exception says your SQL syntax isn't correct.  Try printing the `queryString` and running it separately.

Comment: Make sure that your array is what you want it to be. I have a feeling, that it don't

Comment: I think you have an extra `}` that closes your `for` loop before it gets to the if statements. Miscopied code perhaps? Or does it actually look like that in your code?

Comment: Check your earlier question for how to get the role_ids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21787827/this-list-is-returning-map-how-can-i-get-the-integer-values-from-the-map

Answer (score 1):

There's a bug in the logic that outputs the list of map values. You're outputting the *entire* map rather than just one value you want.

Change this line:

```
roleIds += m.toString();
```

To:

```
roleIds += m.get(i);
```

Comment: `m` isn't declared anywhere.

Comment: @DavidConrad based on the calls made on it and the output produced, it's a Map that must be defined elsewhere. If you read the code, he's using it correctly near the problem line.

Comment: I agree it must be a Map, but I don't think he's using it correctly. If the map does contain something like `{role_id=22}` he would have to use `m.get("role_id")`; `m.get(i)` is just going to give `null`.